# How to trigger some code when a user leaves a page?

Tags: form

I would like to monitor a form in SharePoint. For example when someone leaves the page. How can I do that? I do not want to trigger the code when someone refresh the page or a postback.

Comment: You would need them to take an action (e.g. click a button or link) in order for that to occur. Simply closing the browser or typing in a new URL would not allow you to trigger anything. Is this an application page, InfoPath Form, OOTB SharePoint form?

Comment: It is a article page with a custom webpart. In the custom webpart there is some form with a wizard (step 1, 2, 3, send email).

Comment: do you have access to the source code?